# CakePHP: organise controllers in subfolders

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Is it possible in CakePHP to organise controllers (and models) in subfolders? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but it is deprecated. See the discussion [here](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Organizing-Controllers-into-subfolders-in-CakePHP-2-td5089708.html). The last post on this page describes how to do it in the bootstrap.

Comment: Oh, specifying additional paths! I could do that, but why deprecated? Should I use plugins instead? It's just because my website is divided into sections, each one very separated from the other ones, and I'd like to organise a bit the code (I've got a lot of files!).

Comment: I actually have no idea, as this was promoted in earlier versions. Plugins seem to be the way to go.

Comment: Discussions are not decisions and this depreciation content in the answer answer is simply not accurate.

Answer (score 9):

It's not deprecated at all. You can accomplish this using the App:build and point to your subfolders. For example, if you want to put all of your Twitter models in Model/Twitter to keep your code organized, you can add the following to the `bootstrap.php`:

```
App::build(array(
    'Model' => array(APP . 'Model' . DS . 'Twitter' . DS),
));
```

Now, any model file you put in Model/Twitter will be available when you call it.

See more here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App::build

Answer (score 1):

For those of you looking for a CakePhp3 version of this answer here is a link to the routing documentation. Use router prefixing that matches your controller sub-namespaces / directory structure.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3 you can define additional class paths in your composer.json (see http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#additional-class-paths)

Btw if you want to organize your template files in subfolders you have to add their paths in your app.php at `App.paths`
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration

Just in case someone else is searching for this piece of information... ;)