# CakePHP routing to deeper layer in controller

Tags: cakephp, controller

I tried creating multiple layer(folder) in controller and by rerouting using like below.

```
Router::connect(
    '/abc',
    array('controller' => '/abc/test', 'action' => 'test')     
);
```

Where from the understand of the full path in CakePHP it would be

```
app/Controller/abc/TestController
```

It was :Not Found: showing in the browser. I wonder if we can do multiple layer down in CakePHP controller or what I can do in this case.

Comment: I don't think it's recommended to group controllers into subfolders. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836128/cakephp-organise-controllers-in-subfolders

Answer (score 0):

As @joshua.paling wrote in comment to your question I don't think that's possible with cake. If you need group you controllers you should look at [plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html) for dividing you app to modules.

Other options would be setup routing for different paths - but I don't think that isn't the case of your question.